# javascript new Date() is not working properly in some android devices?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am using new Date () for getting time from javascript in cordova application.In some devices the time had changed and date is correct.but in mobile setting the time and time zone is correct only.

Please anyone tell me how the time is changed, i have to achive to get new Date() without using external plugins.

Ex: in mobile setting device date and time is Thu Apr 06 2017 18:40:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time). i also used to convert new Date() into string.but getting wrong time only in my app.
but in my app its showing when am getting the time its showing 08:15.How it will be?

Comment: user Calender.getInstance().getTime()

Comment: am asking javascript date is not working in android.its a hybrid app.

Comment: I am sorry dont follow it.

Comment: have you got any solution for this ??? @AvishekDas

Comment: anyone have a solution here?  I have an LG K20+, the phone shows the correct EDT, but my cordova app is reporting local time as PDT.  I tested my code with a samsung phone and that device is reporting the correct date/time.  How can this be fixed...this looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe globalization plugin help you http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-globalization/index.html#page-toc-source

Look this example:

```
 navigator.globalization.dateToString(
    new Date(),
    function (date) { alert('date: ' + date.value + '\n'); },
    function () { alert('Error getting dateString\n'); },
    { formatLength: 'short', selector: 'date and time' }
);
```

Comment: without using external plugin??